# error: package play.mvc does not exist

Tags: java, playframework-2.1

I am starting a test project with Play 2.1.2 and I want to try a modular approach. I have created a sub project and I have created some classes in it. I'm using eclipse, and I have successfully opened the project and sub-project in my workspace. Everything seemed to be fine. Until I fired up the terminal and tried to run it. It resolved all dependencies from `Build.scala` then spouted quite a few errors, from which the first was :

```
error: package play.mvc does not exist
```

from one class file in the sub project that seems fine from eclipse.

Since I don't know what information is required to help anyone fine the answer to this, I'll be updating this question with the required information. Meanwhile, if any kind soul would already spot the problem from this simple question, I'll be much grateful to know why I'm having this.

Thanks!

** **Update** **

Here is the `build.scala` file

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "testapp"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean,

    // Postgre SQL 9.1
    "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4",

    // Deadbolt 2    
    "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.1-RC2",
    "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-scala" % "2.1-RC2"
  )

  val testappSubProject = Project(
    appName + "-subtest", file("modules/sub-project")
  ).settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.10.0"
  )

  val main = play.Project(
    appName, appVersion, appDependencies
  ).dependsOn(testappSubProject).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here

    resolvers += Resolver.url("Objectify Play Repository", url("http://schaloner.github.com/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
    resolvers += Resolver.url("Objectify Play Snapshot Repository", url("http://schaloner.github.com/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns) 
  )

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testappSubProject` does not depend on Play, so if you try to import `play.mvc` in this project, it will fails.

Comment: Or make it as play.Project()

Comment: Or thought of that soon after I wrote the question. That was easy! Thanks!